# Get value of jquery ui dialog in code behind

Tags: c#, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery ui dialog that has a radio button list on it. I need to call a server side method when the user clicks ok and I need to pass the selected value. I tried doing it by calling an ajax method on and passing the selected value as a parameter. This worked great (the value was passed) but I could not access a cookie from the method (got error - Request is not available in this context), which makes sense being that this is an ajax request. Here is the code:

```
$("#dialogReject").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Reject": function () {
                    var value = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "/myPage.aspx/RejectDocumentWM",
                        data: "{'rejectReason':'" + value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function (result) { alert('error'); }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

RejectDocument():

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void RejectDocumentWM(string rejectReason)
    {
        MyNamespace.myPage page = new MyNamespace.myPage();
        page.RejectDocument(rejectReason);
    }

 protected void RejectDocument(string rejectReason)
    {
        batch batch = (batch)Session["Batch"];
        if (client.RejectDocument(batch.GetCurrentDoc().icn, rejectReason, Request.Cookies["username"].Value)) //here is where I get the error
        {
            NextDocument();
        }
    }
```

I tried doing it by putting the value into a hidden field and then calling a button click which calls a server side method. My problem here was that the hidden field's value was always blank even though it set properly in the client script. Here is the code for that:

```
            $("#dialogReject").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Reject": function () {
                    var value = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
                    $('[id$="hdfRejectReason"]').val(value); //this sets properly
                    $('[id$="btnRejectDoc"]').click();
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

 protected void btnRejectDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        batch batch = (batch)Session["Batch"];
        if (client.RejectDocument(batch.GetCurrentDoc().icn, hdfRejectReason.Value, Request.Cookies["username"].Value))
//hdfRejectReason.Value is blank
        {
            NextDocument();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas for me? I am at my wits end. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, is this hf is in 'popup' or in 'main page' section?

Second, in stackoverflow, we discused and set other (better?) way to set hidden field value in jQuery:

```
    <div class="hfFoo-wrap">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfFoo" />
    </div>

function FooBarFunction() {
    var hfFoo = $('.hfFoo-wrap input[type=hidden]');
    hfFoo.val('Bar');
    var isBar = hfFoo.val();
}
```

Maybe in btnRejectDoc_Click have other 'null' or 'empty' params?

Third: I prefere FrameDialog with 'aspx' page and 'callback delegate'.

1. create popup as 'aspx' page
2. open popup from 'main page' by jQuery as  jQuery.FrameDialog
3. close dialog from 'aspx-popup' as 'close popup' (jQuery.FrameDialog.closeDialog();)
4. on 'main page' catch callback delegate (with params from popup) and set hidden field there

Comment: I don't have a problem setting the value - it sets properly. I put an alert after I set the value and its showing the proper value. The problem is the code behind does not recognize the value that was set. And no, I don't have any other parameters.

Comment: This hf is in 'popup' or in 'main page' section?

Comment: It was in the pop-up. I moved it to the main page and it works now. Thanks for pointing me in that direction. If you put it as an answer (that the hf needs to be in the main page) I'll mark it. Thanks again!